# Изменение цвета текста выпадающего меню Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, color, dropdown

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поменять цвет текста Bootstrap navbar dropdown в "схлопнутом" виде (см картинку)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

разобралась, но не нашла как удалить вопрос)))

```
.dropdown-menu a{
    color: #c68c45 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover{
    color: #F7BE6F !important;
}
```

может кому пригодится=)